# Gremlin Python: Selecting the vertex with the earliest date and by alphanumeric order

Tags: python, graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm using Neptune as my graph db.

I have vertices with an ID (UUID), Label, and Date.

I can pull all properties of multiple vertices like this:

```
g.V('633378c3-b016-433a-a3ca-c1662982f970').valueMap(True).as_('test1').V('6e5db9a0-2946-4d98-9657-07a3fe825598').valueMap(True).as_('test2').select('test1', 'test2').toList()

[{'test11': {<T.id: 1>: '633378c3-b016-433a-a3ca-c1662982f970', 'Date': [datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 7, 20, 0)], <T.label: 3>: 'sample_id'}, 'test2': {<T.id: 1>: '6e5db9a0-2946-4d98-9657-07a3fe825598', 'Date': [datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 7, 20, 0)], <T.label: 3>: 'sample_id'}}]
```

But I want to only pull the vertex with the earliest date, and if both dates are the same, I want to pull the one earlier in alphanumeric order.

If I try

```
g.V('633378c3-b016-433a-a3ca-c1662982f970').valueMap(True).as_('test1').V('6e5db9a0-2946-4d98-9657-07a3fe825598').valueMap(True).as_('test2').select('test1', 'test2').order().by('Date').toList()
```

I get the error:

```
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 498: {"requestId":"101ab1d2-ced8-4a20-adc9-5deb97e1e801","code":"UnsupportedOperationException","detailedMessage":"java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get that error is because you are trying to treat the result of `valueMap()` which is a `Map` as a graph `Element` as the `by('Date')` syntax only works on `Element`. Given the description of what you want to do, I think you can simplify your traversal to:

```
g.V('633378c3-b016-433a-a3ca-c1662982f970','6e5db9a0-2946-4d98-9657-07a3fe825598'). 
  order().by('Date').by(T.id).
  limit(1).
  valueMap(True).toList()
```

I assume that by "one earlier in alphanumeric order" you meant the UUID which is why I added the second `by()` modulator with `T.id`.

If you want to preserve both vertices for later use in the traversal then you have a number of options. You could do:

```
g.V('633378c3-b016-433a-a3ca-c1662982f970','6e5db9a0-2946-4d98-9657-07a3fe825598'). 
  order().by('Date').by(T.id).
  fold()
```

and access them by position with `limit(local,1)`and `tail(local)` respectively. Using that same approach you could also `project()` them to a `Map`:

```
g.V('633378c3-b016-433a-a3ca-c1662982f970','6e5db9a0-2946-4d98-9657-07a3fe825598'). 
  order().by('Date').by(T.id).
  fold().
  project('a','b').
    by(limit(local,1)).
    by(tail(local))
```

Comment: This works! Instead of converting it to a list, what if I wanted to store the first and second result as variables? I want to batch a bunch of queries together so if I can recall these variables later in later queries it'd be more efficient.

Comment: are you saying you would have pairs of ids that you would query? i'm not sure i follow what you're asking.

Comment: So for example

g.V('633378c3-b016-433a-a3ca-c1662982f970','6e5db9a0-2946-4d98-9657-07a3fe825598'). 
  order().by('Date').by(T.id)

Would now return the two vertices in sorted order. I want to save the first vertex as variable 'a', and second vertex as variable 'b' now that I know 'a' is going to be the earliest/alphanumeric vertex.

Comment: And I mean variables in gremlin, not in python, since I want to get rid of the toList() and batch a few queries together and skip the intermediary python steps.

Comment: what is your goal in the later queries you intend to batch? do you intend to use both variables in some way later traversal? or are you saying you are batching the same sort of logic that you had in your question, in other words, "pairs of ids" that need resolution given the logic `order().by('Date').by(T.id)`?

Comment: Yes, I intend to use both variables in a later traversal.
I suppose I could do something like g.V('633378c3-b016-433a-a3ca-c1662982f970','6e5db9a0-2946-4d98-9657-07a3fe825598'). order().by('Date').by(T.id).limit(1).as_('a').V('633378c3-b016-433a-a3ca-c1662982f970','6e5db9a0-2946-4d98-9657-07a3fe825598'). order().by('Date', desc).by(T.id, desc).limit(1).as_('b') but that seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting the error: TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable
due to the "by(limit(local,1)).by(tail(local))" steps. It works fine after the project but not when I add those.

Comment: Nevermind, figured out in python I had to use Scope.local

Comment: Although after I project those values I can't seem to use them in subsequent queries. For instance after I'll add on to the traversal with something like ".V('a').valueMap(True).toList()" it will output nothing since I think it's trying to find the vertex with the index of 'a' instead of the vertex that I projected to the 'a' variable.

Comment: It's hard for me to say what you should do without better context. I think you should consider a new question with more details of what you want to achieve in the latter part of your query and perhaps a Gremlin script to create some sample data